# Okta oauth2 integration with spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, okta

I am trying to authenticate all the request coming to my rest endpoints especially POST requests. I have integrated okta ouath2 with my spring boot application. According to my WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implementation i am authenticating all the request to /login endpoint but i am not specifically blocking my REST endpoints. Honestly speaking I am not sure what is happening under the hood. I am using @EnableOAuth2Sso annotation.

If I block my REST endpoints from security config, i always get forbidden status code(403) for my calls. So I decided to only authenticate calls to /login endpoint and not to all the specific REST endpoints.

security config file :-

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/login" )
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/**", "/webjars/**", "/error**")
        .permitAll();
    }
}
```

Filter class :-

```
@Component
@Order(1)
@Slf4j
public class TransactionFilter implements Filter {

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);

        String requestURL = req.getRequestURL().toString();

        if(session != null){
            SecurityContextImpl sci = (SecurityContextImpl) session.getAttribute("SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT");

            if (sci != null) {
                OAuth2Authentication oAuth2Authentication = (OAuth2Authentication) sci.getAuthentication();
                System.out.println(" oAuth2Authentication "+oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication());
            }
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

These is how my rest endpoint looks, I am trying to secure access to it using okta auth2:-

```
@RequestMapping("/api/v1")
public interface DataPullClientApi {

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/DataPullPipeline", method = POST, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    ResponseEntity startDataPull(HttpEntity<String> inputJson);
}
```

After successful authentication at /login, i am getting redirected to index.html which just have a input text field where I input the json and on clicking submit it calls the /DataPullPipeline Rest endpoint provided above through some ajax calls.

**Actual results :-**
when i go to http://localhost:8080/login, i am getting redirected to okta login page, which is expected. After i authenticate myself i am redirected to index.html. In the index.html i enter the input json which is then sent to server side REST endpoint which is also correct.
**The result of println statement in filter class is something like this 'oAuth2Authentication org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@c04b48fc: Principal: snautiyal@xxx.com; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: {ver=1, jti=xxxxx, iss=https://dev-xxxx.okta.com/oauth2/default, aud=api://default, iat=xxx, exp=xxx, cid=xxx, uid=xxx, scp=[profile, openid, email], sub=snautiyal@xxxxx.com}; Not granted any authorities'**

My Questions :-
1) Are my endpoints really secure with this approach, i am doing nothing to secure them, i am just securing my /login endpoint. I don't know if this secures rest endpoints in the redirected page. If my rest endpoints are not secure what should i do to secure them.
2) In my filter class I am able to get information of logged in user from SecurityContextImpl. Line 'System.out.println(" oAuth2Authentication "+oAuth2Authentication.getUserAuthentication());' prints details of the user logged in. Is this approach of getting logged-in user information correct. I am getting this information even if I have put no authentication on my REST endpoints. Is it safe to reply on this information for logged in user.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: If you can hit your rest endpoints and get response even when you are not authenticates. Your REST endpoints are not secured. You don't seem to have OAuth2.0 understanding. I recommend you read the OAuth2.0 RFC first and other literatures on OAuth2.0

Comment: when i go to localhost:8080/login, i am asked for okta login, when i put my credentials into okta, i am redirected to index.html where i put my input json in the text box and after this when i click on submit, my REST endpoint is called and the input json is submitted. If i am not authenticated , how am i getting Principal object from SecurityContextImpl with isAuthenticated to true.

Comment: That's on UI. What if an attacker directly invokes your REST APIs without going through the UI?

Comment: But REST endpoints can simply be secured by putting a check in filter, the check should verify if the SecurityContextImpl have information about the user and the principal object from SecurityContextImpl is authenticated or not.